Unity keep non Mono Behaviour inspector values
I'm working with Unity and have encountered an issue related to serialized non-MonoBehaviour classes. Specifically, I have a PlayerController class that derives from MonoBehaviour and contains a public field of type GroundDetection. The GroundDetection class does not derive from MonoBehaviour and is serialized in the Unity Inspector.
Here's a simplified example:
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GroundDetection groundDetection;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class GroundDetection
{
    public float RayDistance;
    public LayerMask GroundLayer;

    public GroundDetection(float rayDistance, LayerMask groundLayer)
    {
        RayDistance = rayDistance;
        GroundLayer = groundLayer;
    }
}

When I modify the GroundDetection fields in the Inspector and then create a new instance of GroundDetection using new GroundDetection(), all the fields reset to their default values.
For instance:
groundDetection = new GroundDetection(this, groundDetection.RayDistance, groundDetection.GroundLayer);

While initializing fields in the constructor (as shown) works, it's not an ideal solution for multiple non-MonoBehaviour scripts.
Is there a better way to retain the values of serialized fields in non-MonoBehaviour classes when they are edited from the Unity Inspector?
Any guidance or best practices would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!
Edit:
using the constructor like this is also not the best way but its the most convenient solution i found for now to still have control which fields actually should be set and still keep the call simple enough to use it for many different classes and fields.
For example like this:
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GroundDetection groundDetection;
   
    void Start()
    {
       groundDetection = new GroundDetection(groundDetection);
    }

}


I can think of these approaches:

Use value types
[System.Serializable]
public struct GroundDetection
{
    public float RayDistance;
    public LayerMask GroundLayer;
}

var groundDetection2 = groundDetection;


Use JsonUtility
static T CloneWithJson<T>(T srcObj)
    => JsonUtility.FromJson<T>(JsonUtility.ToJson(srcObj));

var groundDetection2 = CloneWithJson(groundDetection);


Enable C#10 and use record types
[System.Serializable]
public record class GroundDetection
{
    public float RayDistance;
    public LayerMask GroundLayer;
}

var groundDetection2 = groundDetection with {};




I attempted to use records, but since Unity is still using C# 9, it doesn't support record classes. You can see the documentation in the link below.
Using JSON serialization feels like a hack, similar to the solution I previously mentioned. Structs add unnecessary complexity, especially without the new auto-default feature for fields available in C# 11.
I'm looking for a more elegant solution, but it seems that Unity's current limitations are making this difficult. Anyways thanks I appreciate the help though.
https://docs.unity3d.com/6000.0/Documentation/Manual/CSharpCompiler.html

You can use a serializable class, it doesn't have to be a struct.

@RakkanMain I have a link in the answer to teach you how to enable c#.

where is the link? I guess you are talking about c# 11 or higher?
